# Cambios inesperados en una matriz de objetos utilizando Node.js

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente con un código que realice (parecido a lo que seria Hashing Abierto).

tengo el siguiente código en javascript:

```js
let o = function(){
 this.a;

 this.geta=function(){return this.a;}

 this.seta=function(a){this.a=a;}
};

let i,j,l;
let a=[];
let p=[2,7,9,2,6];

let aux=new o();
aux.seta(p[0]);
a[0]=new Array(1);
a[0][0]=new o();
a[0][0]=aux;

console.log('Procesing ',p[0]);

for(i=1;i<p.length;i++){
  aux.seta(p[i])
  for(j=0;j<a.length;j++){
    if(a[j][0].geta()==aux.geta()){
      l=a[j].length;
      a[j][l]=new o();
      a[j][l]=aux;
    }
  }
  if(j==a.length){
    a[j]=new Array(1);
      a[j][0]=new o();
      a[j][0]=aux;
  }
  console.log('Procesing ',p[i]);
}
console.log('---------------------------------------------------------------------');
for(k=0;k<a.length;k++){
  for(n=0;n<a[k].length;n++){
    console.log('Value:',a[k][n].geta());
  }
  console.log('End of Bucket ',k);

}
```

Al ejecutarlo , en el arreglo a me figuran 4 buckets todos con numeros 6 nada mas.Cuando en realidad deberian figurar el 2,7,9.

Muchas Gracias;)

Comment: Haces cosas muy raras (e innecesarias) en el código; me está costando horrores ver qué quieres hacer realmente. ¿Podrías explicarlo más detalladamente?

Comment: Pues basicamente quiero realizar un codigo que sea parecido al Hashing Abierto (digo 'parecido' asi luego puedo basarme en Hashings mas complejos.).
Tengo un arreglo numerico p ,donde en este caso tengo numeros repetidos.Lo que quiero hacer es guardar todos los elementos del arreglo p en el arreglo 'a'.
Lo que hay que tener en cuenta es que los numeros que son repetidos deberian guardarse todos en un segundo arreglo que estaria alojado en una posicion del arreglo principal 'a'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro del primer ciclo `for` estas asignando a la variable `aux` el i-esimo valor del arreglo `p` y luego guardas aux en la matriz `a` pero no estas guardando un nuevo objeto, estas guardando el mismo objeto una y otra vez por lo que en la última iteración del primer ciclo for guardas en la variable aux el valor de 6 y como todos los valores de la matriz son ese objeto aux al imprimirlos te muestran ese valor, agregue una linea de código para crear un nuevo objeto `o` por cada iteración del primer ciclo for

```js
let o = function(){
 this.a;

 this.geta=function(){return this.a;}

 this.seta=function(a){this.a=a;}
};

let i,j,l;
let a=[];
let p=[2,7,9,2,6];

let aux=new o();
aux.seta(p[0]);
a[0]=new Array(1);
a[0][0]=new o();
a[0][0]=aux;

console.log('Procesing ',p[0]);

for(i=1;i<p.length;i++){
  aux = new o();
  aux.seta(p[i]);
  for(j=0;j<a.length;j++){
    if(a[j][0].geta()==aux.geta()){
      l=a[j].length;
      a[j][l]=new o();
      a[j][l]=aux;
    }
  }
  if(j==a.length){
    a[j]=new Array(1);
      a[j][0]=new o();
      a[j][0]=aux;
  }
  console.log('Procesing ',p[i]);
}
console.log('---------------------------------------------------------------------');
for(k=0;k<a.length;k++){
  for(n=0;n<a[k].length;n++){
    console.log('Value:',a[k][n].geta());
  }
  console.log('End of Bucket ',k);

}
```

Comment: Ahi lo pude resolver , muchas gracias!!